# Issue with .addRole &.removeRole

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to create a mute command which will remove ALL your roles and add mute role, after a mute time it should return ALL your roles and take mute role. When I'm trying to take (or return) ALL roles it writes next:

```
(node:3720) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Supplied parameter was neither a Role nor a Snowflake.
```

That takes the roles (and gives a muterole) after using mute command:

```
rmember.addRole(muterole.id) && rmember.removeRole(takenroles);
```

And that returns the roles (and takes a muterole) after mutetime expires:

```
rmember.removeRole(muterole.id) && rmember.addRole(takenroles) ;
```

That's how I'm trying to take roles:

```
let rmember = message.mentions.members.first()
let takenroles = rmember.roles
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`GuildMember.addRole()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=addRole) and [`GuildMember.removeRole()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=removeRole) only add/remove a *single* [Role](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role) per call. To remove multiple at once, use [`GuildMember.addRoles()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=addRoles) and [`GuildMember.removeRoles()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=removeRoles).

```js
Promise.all([
  rmember.addRole(muterole),
  rmember.removeRoles(takenroles)
])
  .then(() => console.log('Muted.'))
  .catch(console.error);
```

Conversely...

```js
Promise.all([
  rmember.removeRole(muterole),
  rmember.addRoles(takenroles)
])
  .then(() => console.log('Unmuted.'))
  .catch(console.error);
```